# Remove "example" between ahref string

Tags: notepad++, html, website, html5

Can you guys help me with this?

I know there exist a ctrl + alt and then select but i want to use a code something like(example: *(<a) "[0-9a-f-]*")*

```
<a "Testt 22" href="https://test.com" data-href="https://test.com/">

to 

<a href="https://test.com" data-href="https://test.com/">
```

Cause i just made simple [info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hZLn.png) example

Comment: Is `"Testt nn` **always** just after `<a `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<a \K.*?(?=href=)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<a              # <a and a space
\K              # forget it
.*?             # 0 or more any character, not greedy
(?=href=)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have href= after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]